# How to write a jquery function that can return 3 possible options

Tags: jquery

I have a basic points counter widget that I am working on.  I had an earlier question that got answered to help me get moving.  But I have a final question. Basically, I have a function that is going to return true or false, but I need a third option.

the logic is:

- if input char count is in range, user gets points
- if user edits and count stays in range no new points
- if user edits and count goes out of range after it was in range, then user looses points

I think I hve this right, just not sure how to complete the function.

http://jsfiddle.net/jNtJA/8/

```
 var check = false;

 function titleInc() {
     var length = $('#title').val().length;
     if (length >= 5 && length <= 10 && !check) {
         check = true;
         return true;
     } else if (check  && length < 5 && length > 10) {
         // Set the function to return DECREMENT
     } else {
         return false;
     }

     $('#title').blur(function () {
         var current = parseInt($('#end_val').val(), 10);
         if (titleInc()) {
             $('#end_val').val(current + 12);
         } else if(  ){
         // THERE NEEDS TO BE A WAY TO DECREMENT
         }
     });

 });
```

Comment: How about returning a number?

Comment: Javascript can return numbers, as well as booleans

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var options = {
         increment: 1,
         decrement: 2, 
         doNothing: 3
     };

 function titleInc() {
     var length = $('#title').val().length;
     if (length >= 5 && length <= 10 && !check) {
         check = true;
         return options.increment;
     } else if (check  && length < 5 && length > 10) {
         return options.decrement;
     } else {
         return options.doNothing;
     }

     $('#title').blur(function () {
         var current = parseInt($('#end_val').val(), 10),
             option = titleInc();
         if (option === options.increment) {
             $('#end_val').val(current + 12);
         } else if(option === options.decrement){
             $('#end_val').val(current - 12);
         }
     });
```

Comment: This is an elegant and extensible solution

Comment: I messed with this but the decrement doesn't appear to be working... Am I missing something: http://jsfiddle.net/8mPLJ/

Comment: `length < 20 && length > 120`.  This says that the length must be less than 20 and greater than 120.  I think you mean less than 20 or greater than 120. Also, `dialCheck = true` is an assignment, not boolean logic.  You probably want `dialcheck && (length < 20 || length > 120)`

Comment: one more question: if I was to use this for multiple fields would I need to create more than one dialCheck vars?  like dialCheckTitle, dialCheckDesc... or will dialCheck become contextual per function?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your design will be or what you want, but it sounds like you'll want multiple dialChecks and one dialOptions enum.